# Create bean of legacy classes without modification and without xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, data-annotations

I have some existing legacy helper class  without bean annotation and without xml configuration. 
I want to create beans for same classes without modification (without adding annotations) and without any extra configuration in xml.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible and pretty straightforward. You need to create your own class and annotate it with `@Configuration` and then create a method annotated with `@Bean` returning your helper class. Something like that:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {

    @Bean
    public HelperClass helperClassName() {
        return new HelperClass();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call one `@Bean` method from another using `@Configuration` and get a fully initialized instance, as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    @Value("Hello, world!")
    public String value;
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Foo createFoo() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.value); // Prints null - foo not initialized yet
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar createBar() {
        Foo foo = createFoo();
        System.out.println(foo.value); // Prints Hello, world! - foo have been initialized by the interceptor
        return new Bar(foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and register your classes manually.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({
    LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration.Legacy1.class,
    LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration.Legacy2.class,
    LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration.Legacy3.class
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class)
public class LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration implements 
  BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry) throws BeansException {
    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition1 = new RootBeanDefinition(Legacy1.class, Legacy1::new);
    beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition(Legacy1.class.getName(), beanDefinition1);

    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition2 = new RootBeanDefinition(Legacy2.class, Legacy2::new);
    beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition(Legacy2.class.getName(), beanDefinition2);

    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition3 = new RootBeanDefinition(Legacy3.class, Legacy3::new);
    beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition(Legacy3.class.getName(), beanDefinition3);
}

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
    // n00p
}

class Legacy1 {

}

class Legacy2 {

}

class Legacy3 {

  }
}
```

Heres a test confirming the beans are registered:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LegacyBeansAutoConfigurationTest {
  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext context;

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
    Assertions.assertThat(context.getBeanNamesForType(LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration.Legacy1.class)).isNotNull();
    Assertions.assertThat(context.getBeanNamesForType(LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration.Legacy2.class)).isNotNull();
    Assertions.assertThat(context.getBeanNamesForType(LegacyBeansAutoConfiguration.Legacy3.class)).isNotNull();
}
}
```